# How to map the ActionIconTapped event handler of PhoneTextBox using mvvmcross

Tags: mvvmcross

I am very new to MVVMCross.

I would like to map the the `ActionIconTapped` event handler of `PhoneTextBox` using MVVMCross.

Answer (score 0):

To data-bind handlers like these in Windows, you need to use a behaviour to turn the event into a command - there's an article on this for MvvmLight in http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-bind-a-windows-phone-control-event-to-a-command-using-mvvm-light  - the same code should work for MvvmCross - it just uses the `i:EventTrigger` provided by the Blend extensions.

Comment: Hi Stuart, thanks for the reply. I have gone through the link provided and in MVVMLight they are using the RelayCommand to convert the events to commands. Do we have any reference in MVVMCross to do the same thing.

Comment: I thought they were using eventtocommand - maybe try reading up some more and searching "mvvmcross eventocommand"?